# Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb' when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, fedora, pycryptodome

I am trying to generate an executable from a python script using `pyinstaller`. For this I am executing the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --paths /path/to/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages \
   --paths /path/to/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packagesscript.py
```

It generates an executable but when trying to execute it, it gives me an error:

```
OSError: Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb': Not found '_raw_ecb.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', Not found '_raw_ecb.abi3.so', Not found '_raw_ecb.so'
```

When executing

```
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
```

on my Windows 10 machine, everything works fine. On my Fedora machine, however, I get thus error.

How can I prevent this from happening?

**EDIT**

`sys.path` gives the following result:

```
['', '/usr/lib64/python39.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.9', '/usr/lib64/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages', '/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a cryptographic package. The file it cannot find is provided by `python3-pycryptodomex`; try `sudo dnf install python3-pycryptodomex` and see if the problem persists.

**EDIT:** type `python` in the console. When you get the three arrows (`>>>`), type first `import sys` and hit enter. Then, type `sys.path` and post the output.

Comment: I executed the command, but it still gives me the exact same error.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I posted the output to the original question. I also tried including all those paths with the `--paths` flag. Unfortunately, it still fails upon execution.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help, but I'm sure that package provides the required dependencies. It probably cannot find it due to some linking issues (maybe from inside the virtual environment).